# Magento 2.3.4 installation issues

Tags: installation, magento2.3.4

I am trying to install magento 2.3.4 on a LAMP stack on centos. Php version 7.3 and mysql 5.6. Initially setup was giving a 500 error. I searched google and found a suggestion to remove .htaccess. it worked. Now it gives 404 error for admin page after installation and homepage appears without any css and media. If I put the .htaccess back to root folder of magento, it gives 500 error for both admin and magento store.
Can you please help me find the problem.

Comment: Use this command after removing htaccess ->sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  & then check your admin-url set during installation of magento

Comment: You can check this file to find your admin url -> app/etc/env.php  defines in frontname =>